# Mulltivariable limit quesion and my attempt

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given 
$$
F(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & (x,y)=(2y,y) \\
\exp \biggl( \frac{|x-2y|}{x^2 -4xy +4y^2} \biggr) & (x, y) \ne (2y, y)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Task is to examine whether function is continuous at origin and my attempt is as follows:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation as $x\to 0^-$ is not right. When $x\ne 2y$, the quantity $\frac{|x-2y|}{x^2-4xy+4y^2}$ is always positive, it is $\frac{1}{|x-2y|}$. So as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on a path that avoids the line $x=2y$, our function blows up.

Comment: thanks Andre. So limit doesnt exist .am i right ?

Comment: Can you pls tell me where im wrong in this ? . what u have said is also right .but where is problem in what i have done

Comment: The exponential blows up, while if we approach along $x=2y$ the limit is $0$. What I was objecting to was the calculation when $x\ne 2y$. I am surprised that the question is not about $\exp(-|x-2y|/(x-2y)^2)$, which is more interesting.

Comment: sorry i still coudnt get my mistake can u pls explain

Comment: On the right-hand side of your page, dealing with $0^-$, at some point you have $e^{\frac{1}{-x}k}$, which you decide goes to $0$. It doesn't, $-x$ is positive, so the exponential blows up.

Comment: oh ok yes is see now .So limit doesnt exist in this question it seems .what do u say about that?

Comment: The limit does not exist in this question because as you approach along $x=2y$ the "limit" is $0$, but on any other approach the function blows up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it clear

Comment: You are welcome. The calculation as $x\to 0^-$ (if $x\ne 2y$) had a glitch, but you did not even need to make that calculation to show the limit does not exist.